# WCF service using mod_mono

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mono, mod-mono

I am trying to host a WCF service on CentOS using mono 2.10.8 and access it as a REST or SOAP server.

I started an application using mod-mono-server-4 in the folder containing my web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" name="Services.Hello">
                <clear/>
                <endpoint address="http://DOMAIN/service" behaviorConfiguration="HelloBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Services.IHello" />
                <endpoint address="http://DOMAIN/web" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Services.IHello" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="HelloBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="WebBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If I now call `DOMAIN/web?wsdl` or `DOMAIN/service/hello` (`/hello` is the UriTemplate of a WebGetAttribute of a method in IHello) I only get a 404:

> Server Error in '/' Application
>   The resource cannot be found.

I also have a `Service.svc` file containting:

> 

If I call `DOMAIN/Service.svc/hello` I get a SOAP-Error:

> The request message has the target 'http://DOMAIN/Service.svc/hello' with action '' which is not reachable in this service contract

If I start a console application on the server executing the following:

```
WebServiceHost sh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Hello), new Uri("http://localhost:681/service"));
sh.Open();
```

I can access the service on port 680 so mono should be able to run the service, but I need it to run with mod_mono (on port 80).

**What do I need to configure differently?**

In the end I'm trying to host a SyndicationFeed to deliver RSS/Atom-Feeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to get it running ATM:
Create a normal *.asmx-WebService and create a method like:

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle=SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
public XmlDocument Feed()
{
    SyndicationFeed feed = new SyndicationFeed();
    //Fill the feed...
    Atom10FeedFormatter atom = new Atom10FeedFormatter(feed);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(result);
    atom.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Flush();

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(result.ToString());

    return doc;
}
```

Then you can access the feed at `DOMAIN/Service.asmx/Feed`.